# Control filemaker server console from outside [php API]

Tags: php, filemaker

I want to change file status of some files in FileMaker console using a cron / schedular job.

I have not found any other ways of doing this . No apis available .

If anyone know ant third party apis or Filemaker plugins , please suggest.

Comment: Please check the link may be this will help https://community.filemaker.com/thread/72009

Comment: That thread is related to FileMaker layouts , records etc . That is working . But i want to know whether it is possible to access FileMaker server admin console using any API or not ?

Comment: Any commands available for opening/closing file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from FileMaker console there is only one way to control FileMaker Server - it is bash commands on Mac or cmd on Windows.

I saw solutions before which run server side scripting and control Filemaker Server. I suppose you can do this with PHP as well.

e.g. to close all databases

```
fmsadmin close -y -u admin -p pword
```

Here is the link to kb article:

http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14167/~/filemaker-server-command-line-reference

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please let me know , how to reopen a closed file on FileMaker server using cmd?

Comment: You have to navigate into the folder were fmsadmin located and run this: 
fmsadmin open [file ]  -p [password] -u [user] -y

Comment: You can also specify full path to fmsadmin

Comment: while closing file , its showing this error Error: 10904 (No applicable files for this operation)

What might be the cause ? I think , its due to some file path issue on mac . 
My file is present in FileMakerserver /data/databases/test.fm12
Please suggest.

Comment: Check the permissions. You are not looking for FIleMaker database Access Privileges but the username and a password used to access Server console. The file has to be open first. Did you try to list databases with  fmsadmin list files -s

Comment: could be a number of reason, the problem is stackoverflow is not the best format to go over the checklist. One of the FileMaker forums would be abetter choice. https://community.filemaker.com or fmforums.com

Comment: Now FM roadmap for 2017 adds FileMaker admin console api. Huh

Comment: The roadmap is for 2018 and beyond. I do not think there is a new version coming up in 2017

Comment: Now FM 17 has admin console API

Comment: When i am trying execute fmsadmin command from php shell_exec() , backups are not working.  But when i try it using admin user it works. What might be the cause ? Please advise. @Nicolai

Comment: Again, check the access privileges. Most probably the user for php is not included in the FileMaker Admin group. You can also try to login with fmsadmin user through the shell script or add sudo